# Performance tuning - JDBC Connection times

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm wrapping up a small project and I'm doing some performance tuning before the initial release.  It's a web application so it only receives HTTP requests in the form of XHR and page load requests.

At application startup, a DataSource is retrieved from the Tomcat server (via JNDI) and stored in the application.  It's a `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource` and as far as I can tell (from what I've read and observed) it is pooling connections.

In the application, each request to the server gets its own connection opened at the first SQL call (if one occurs).  At the end of each request, the connection is closed (if one was opened).

So as part of my performance tuning, I'm trying to improve the responsiveness of these requests by reducing the time it takes to make the database connection.  **What would you consider to be acceptable amount of time to establish a database connection?**

Here's my benchmarks so far, each request  -

- 324 ms (1st request just after restarting the application)
- 51 ms
- 58 ms
- 56 ms
- 53 ms
- 51 ms
- 49 ms
- 48 ms

After the 1st connection has been open and "closed" it looks like the connection is pooled and reused.  **Is ~50ms a pretty standard amount of time to establish a connection from a pooled data source?**

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

//oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

log.info("Connection made in: " + ((System.nanoTime()-start)/1000000) + " ms.");
```

Comment: How have you determined that it pools connections?  The timings would in my experience be representative for normal "from scratch" network connections.

Comment: No I haven't been able to confirm that it is actually doing any pooling.  Just that the DataSource it is using to get connections inherits the oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource interface.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Do you happen to know what times I should be expecting to see if I were retrieving connections from a connection pool?

Comment: I don't see that you're closing the connection after acquirement. Are you closing it? But to the point, yes, 200~500ms is normal for creating a connection and ~50ms is normal for getting a pooled connection.

Comment: @BalusC sorry for the confusion, that was just a snippet of code to show the benchmarking.  Thanks for confirming the timings

Comment: @BalusC, IIRC the first connection for Oracle is slow over network, but subsequent ones are faster.  A connection in the connection pool should be allocated almost instantly.

Comment: @Thor: most pools turn of autocommit and/or validates the connection beforehand which also costs some (minor) time. @John: print `connection` or `connection.hashCode()` to examine the hashcode. If it's pooled and you're closing a single connection everytime, it should be the same everytime.

Comment: @BalusC the hashcode is differing each time - so I take it that is good enough evidence to say that the datasource is not pooling the connections?

Comment: Hmm, technically, that also depends on the pooled connection implementation (I'm not familiar with the Oracle one). What if you don't close the obtained connections immediately, but only later after benchmarking? It should be about 10~50ms slower per connection.

Comment: The connections are closed later before the response is sent to the client.  I just implemented the Commons DBCP approach that Matt B mentioned in his answer below.  The benchmarks are all below < 1 ms now.  So it looks like the original datasource wasn't pooling connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connections are pooled that means that they are (mostly) kept open the entire time, so there should be no time to wait while a connection is opened (barring scenarios where the new connections need to be created to handle the current workload). Would suggest adding [commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) to your project to guarantee the pooling.